unable to find valid certification path to requested target: how to get root certificate for https://dl.google.com
I am using Android studio Dolphin 2021.3.1. When i build a signed app bundle from my project, everything runs smoothly. When i change to generate a signed APK, i get the above error.
Searching online, there are so many solutions i have tried (disabling VPN, disabling proxy etc) but the one i find logical (but not tried) is getting the root certificate from the below links, import it using keytool. The problem is that these links only work on HTTP and NOT HTTPS (see picture). I therefore have no way of getting the root certificate of https://dl.google.com. Below is the detailed error message/
Execution failed for task ':app:lintVitalAnalyzeRelease'.

Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:detachedConfiguration1'.
Could not download lint-gradle-30.3.1.jar (com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:30.3.1)
> Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/30.3.1/lint-gradle-30.3.1.jar'.
> Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/30.3.1/lint-gradle-30.3.1.jar'.
> The server may not support the client's requested TLS protocol versions: (TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3). You may need to configure the client to allow other protocols to be used. See: https://docs.gradle.org/7.4/userguide/build_environment.html#gradle_system_properties
> PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
Could not download lint-30.3.1.jar (com.android.tools.lint:lint:30.3.1)
> Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/lint/lint/30.3.1/lint-30.3.1.jar'.
> Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/lint/lint/30.3.1/lint-30.3.1.jar'.
> The server may not support the client's requested TLS protocol versions: (TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3). You may need to configure the client to allow other protocols to be used. See: https://docs.gradle.org/7.4/userguide/build_environment.html#gradle_system_properties
> PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
Could not download lint-checks-30.3.1.jar (com.android.tools.lint:lint-checks:30.3.1)
> Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/lint/lint-checks/30.3.1/lint-checks-30.3.1.jar'.
> Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/lint/lint-checks/30.3.1/lint-checks-30.3.1.jar'.
> The server may not support the client's requested TLS protocol versions: (TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3). You may need to configure the client to allow other protocols to be used. See: https://docs.gradle.org/7.4/userguide/build_environment.html#gradle_system_properties
> PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
Could not download lint-api-30.3.1.jar (com.android.tools.lint:lint-api:30.3.1)
> Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/lint/lint-api/30.3.1/lint-api-30.3.1.jar'.
> Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/lint/lint-api/30.3.1/lint-api-30.3.1.jar'.
> The server may not support the client's requested TLS protocol versions: (TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3). You may need to configure the client to allow other protocols to be used. See: https://docs.gradle.org/7.4/userguide/build_environment.html#gradle_system_properties
> PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
Could not download intellij-core-30.3.1.jar (com.android.tools.external.com-intellij:intellij-core:30.3.1)
> Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/external/com-intellij/intellij-core/30.3.1/intellij-core-30.3.1.jar'.
> Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/external/com-intellij/intellij-core/30.3.1/intellij-core-30.3.1.jar'.
> The server may not support the client's requested TLS protocol versions: (TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3). You may need to configure the client to allow other protocols to be used. See: https://docs.gradle.org/7.4/userguide/build_environment.html#gradle_system_properties
> PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
Could not download kotlin-compiler-30.3.1.jar (com.android.tools.external.com-intellij:kotlin-compiler:30.3.1)
> Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/external/com-intellij/kotlin-compiler/30.3.1/kotlin-compiler-30.3.1.jar'.
> Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/external/com-intellij/kotlin-compiler/30.3.1/kotlin-compiler-30.3.1.jar'.
> The server may not support the client's requested TLS protocol versions: (TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3). You may need to configure the client to allow other protocols to be used. See: https://docs.gradle.org/7.4/userguide/build_environment.html#gradle_system_properties
> PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
Could not download uast-30.3.1.jar (com.android.tools.external.org-jetbrains:uast:30.3.1)
> Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/external/org-jetbrains/uast/30.3.1/uast-30.3.1.jar'.
> Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/external/org-jetbrains/uast/30.3.1/uast-30.3.1.jar'.
> The server may not support the client's requested TLS protocol versions: (TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3). You may need to configure the client to allow other protocols to be used. See: https://docs.gradle.org/7.4/userguide/build_environment.html#gradle_system_properties
> PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
Could not download aapt2-proto-7.0.0-beta04-7396180.jar (com.android.tools.build:aapt2-proto:7.0.0-beta04-7396180)
> Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/aapt2-proto/7.0.0-beta04-7396180/aapt2-proto-7.0.0-beta04-7396180.jar'.
> Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/aapt2-proto/7.0.0-beta04-7396180/aapt2-proto-7.0.0-beta04-7396180.jar'.
> The server may not support the client's requested TLS protocol versions: (TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3). You may need to configure the client to allow other protocols to be used. See: https://docs.gradle.org/7.4/userguide/build_environment.html#gradle_system_properties
> PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target


Please make sure your system date is correct. Are you in a corporate environment with an intercepting proxy/middlebox? Because otherwise in recent browsers there should be no problem with https://dl.google.com certificate.

thanks but the system date is correct. am using mobile data not in a corporate environment

Is tethering allowed in your data plan?  Because dl.google.com supports TLS 1.2 and 1.3 thus the error message is totally wrong. Such a situation could only be possible is there is an intercepting device in between.

Yes. I have actually tethered my phone to my laptop. I have turned off BOTH the antivirus and the Windows firewall but still when i try to build the signed APK, it fails with the same error. What puzzles me is building a signed app bundle works seamlessly. Have you tried to open any of those dl.google.com links in the error message? the jar files download in a browser but are NOT HTTPS unfortunately.

The exact URL doesn't matter in case of TLS problems. First the TLS tunnel to dl.google.com has to be established. As I wrote the problems you have are most likely caused by a network middle box. I don't know where it is but somewhere in between your PC and dl.google.com there is something that corrupts your requests. Make sure you no proxy configured anywhere or a VPN running. As I wrote my guess is that your MNO disallows tethering and this is the effect of the anti-tethering measurements. use a different internet provider and most likely it will work.

thanks Robert for your guidance. I tried MTN, Airtel even Lycamobile networks all in vain. in android studio, i set to use NO proxy. I also disconnected the VPN. as a temporary measure, i have added this code to build.gradle (Module:app) lintOptions {
checkReleaseBuilds false
} with this code the APK is built without any errors being showed but i don't believe this is the real solution.
